# JQuery click event on all buttons with id starting with custom text

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button, click

Using JQuery, I need to write a function, called on click for any of the two buttons (edit0, edit1). 
I have the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $('[id^=edit]').click(function() {
              alert("1111");
           });
       </script>
   </head> 
   <body>
       <button id="edit0" class="edit"> edit </button>
       <button id="edit1" class="edit"> edit </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run it, nothing happens on button click.
I tried to replace the script with:

```
$('button[class="edit"]').click(function() {
    alert('1111');
});
```

But the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use [CSS3 [attribute^=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) to implement 'click event on all buttons with id starting with custom text' as you wish, like below.

```js
$('button[id^="edit"]').click(function() {
  alert('111');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head> 
   <body>
       <button id="edit0" class="edit"> edit </button>
       <button id="edit1" class="edit"> edit </button>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $('[id^=edit]').click(function() {
              alert("1111");
           });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And also, put your code just before the closure `</body>` tag to ensure your dom is ready when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I normally see that syntax for addressing custom attributes, try this.

```
$('button.edit').click(function() {
    alert('1111');
});
```

Also put your script below your HTML. Or use a jQuery on document ready. Remember JavaScript/JQuery are executed sequentially.